# Error: Could not find or load main class FirstProgram

Tags: java, eclipse

When running the following code I get the error Error: Could not find or load main class FirstProgram

I am a newbie programmer and I was wondering if anyone could please help me and tell what is wrong with this code?

```
public class FirstProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String text = "in the name of god";
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you try running this class? Is it **all** the code the source file contains?

Comment: i run it with ctrl+F11, yes its all of it

Comment: This program runs fine. Have you put it in a Java project, under src folder (or src/main/java if using Maven)?

Comment: In the Window menu, click "Show View", and choose "Problems". Any error listed in that view?

Comment: @jb nizet no there is nothing.

Comment: Maybe automatic compilation is tuned off. In the Project menu, is the "Build Automatically" option turned on? What happens if you choose click "Project - Build Project"?

Comment: No about Java project or no about src folder?

Comment: yes its on but when i swich it to off it didnt work any way!!    i couldn't find "Project - Build Project"

Comment: @atao no, actually i dont know much about this

Comment: OK. So the first thing is to create a Java project: File > New > Project... > Java > Java Project. Under this new project, you should have a (source) folder named "src": put your class under it. Select it and run it with Ctrl + F11.

Comment: oh i already did that, it still dosent work!!

Comment: Strange. It should run fine. May be a wrong installation of Eclipse: is it your really first trial under Eclipse?

Comment: yes its the first one!! yes i think it must be for installation!! i installed SDK before Eclipse is it possible that the problem is for that?

Comment: Have you tried to compile it manually? Go to a terminal/command prompt, `cd` to your directory and run `javac FirstProgram.java`. Then try running it with `java FirstProgram`. Does this give any errors?

Comment: @Charlie how can i go to terminal/command prompt?

Comment: After having done @Charlie recommandations, come back under Eclipse and run Project > Clean... then select the class and Ctrl + F11

Comment: @mahmoodmolazade On Windows: Go to start, search for and open `cmd`. On Mac: Go to Spotlight, search for and open `Terminal`. On Linux: This fully depends on your distribution and setup.

Comment: About terminal: what is your OS?

Comment: Check also the build path. Select your project, right click, then Build Path > Configure Build Path... > Source. First check that "Source folders on build path" contains {your project's name}/src. Then check: Default output folder = {your project's name}/bin